# Selenium call function Java Scipt

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to call a function after selenium sees and get the text of a link on page,

```
driver.get("https://www.guerrillamail.com/");
driver.findElement(By.id('inbox-id')).getText().then(function(gm){
address = gm + "@sharklasers.com";
var output = new Buffer(address, 'hex');
console.log(output);
mailExistsCheck();
var query = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'confirm@ksmobile.com ')]")));
query.click();
var query2 = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.partialLinkText("iptlogin")));
query2.getText();
var target = query2.getText();
```

aftter selenium finds this `driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.partialLinkText("iptlogin")));` I want to start a function called `activateMail(target)`.

i Need to do something simular to this

```
var link = target.includes("iptlogin");

if (link = true) {
activateMail(target);
console.log("True");
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: I Edited Question

Comment: Your locator will find the element you are looking for. If it doesn't find it, the wait will throw a timeout exception. If the exception isn't thrown, call `activateMail()`.

Answer (score 1):

@Devin, If you wants to run Javascript with selenium web driver use `JavaScriptExecutor` method, with the Following syntax  :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript(" var link = target.includes('iptlogin'); if (link == true) { activateMail(target); console.log('True'); } ");
```

Comment: Have the fixed the syntax errors. You needed to use `'` instead of `"`, else it breaks the syntax

Answer (score 0):

You will use something like below

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.partialLinkText("iptlogin"))).then(
 () => driver.executeScript("activateMail()")
)
```

or you can even use it like below

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.partialLinkText("iptlogin")))

driver.isElementPresent(by.partialLinkText('iptlogin')).then(
 () => driver.executeScript("activateMail()")
)
```

2nd one makes sure the element is present then only the function is executed. First one doesn't gurantee that